# Unable to sort due to error 1084 sort reference is not valid

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I am beginner in field of VBA and would be grateful if anyone could help me on this.

Basically `r1` and `c1` are variables for selecting row and columns which helps me in selecting the defined range.

However when I try to sort this selected range, `error 1084` pops up. I have tried many versions of sort method but still the problem continues. This is the code that I have

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(r1 + 5000, c1 + 8)), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(r1 + 5000, c1 + 8))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these two lines

```
Key:=Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(r1 + 5000, c1 + 8))
```

and

```
.SetRange Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(r1 + 5000, c1 + 8))
```

Your range and the cells object are not fully qualified. Try this (**Untested**)

Also in `.SortFields.Add`, the `Key:` should refer to only a single column. For example if you are sorting on column 1 then change `Key:=Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(r1 + 5000, c1 + 8))` to `Key:=Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(r1 + 5000, 1))`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

With ws.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, 1), ws.Cells(r1 + 5000, 1)), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, 1), ws.Cells(r1 + 5000, c1 + 8))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Somehow I still prefer the Excel 2003's way of sorting. For example

```
ws.Somerng.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply however the Error still continues.Not sure if it has anything to do with my range selection.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?  Also what is the value of r1 and c1?

Comment: well r1 is 7 and c1 is 26 and the error comes at .apply

Comment: I have updated the above post. You may have to refresh it. Now try it.

Comment: In that case change `ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, 1), ws.Cells(r1 + 5000, 1))` to `ws.Range(ws.Cells(8, c1+1), ws.Cells(r1 + 5000, c1+1))`

Comment: This time the code ran through but nothing got sorted actually.

Comment: What is your datarange? including headers

Comment: Finally was able to resolve the problem. Found that I was not entering the key right. Thanks a ton.